# cannot access phpmyadmin from web browser

Tags: phpmyadmin

**Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) x86-64**

I've installed **phpmyadmin** and **httpd** (apache - **httpd-2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1.x86_64**);

I've configured/edit phpmyadmin from /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf

Restarted Apache and I get an error of Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin/ on this server.

My conf file, here 42.108.56.117 (I've edited this) is my own IP and 4.4.4.4 is my server IP.

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 42.108.56.117
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 42.108.56.117
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 42.108.56.117
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 42.108.56.117
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

I've also tried using this solution from stackoverflow but it didn't worked, anyone got an answer to this problem?

Replaced this:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        # Apache 2.4
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 127.0.0.1
            Require ip ::1
        </RequireAny>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        # Apache 2.2
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Allow from ::1
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

With this: (but still it didn't worked)

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny 
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Still looking for an answer to this problem....

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the answer,

I first edited the conf to this;

```
    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       #Require ip 127.0.0.1
       #Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

And restarted apache and done, it is working fine for me.

If anyone ever face this problem, do not hesitate to comment here I will be sure to help out in any way possible. Good day!